# Como fazer download de arquivos da WEB em pasta interna do aplicativo feito no Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app

Bom dia, estou baixando arquivos que estão em uma hospedagem própria para serem acessados por um aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo (consigo fazer normalmente utilizando os comandos citado mais a baixo), porém os arquivos ficam salvos na pasta padrão de DOWNLOADS do Android, minha intenção não é ficar acumulando estes arquivos no aparelho, ou esperar que o usuário exclua manualmente, gostaria em salva-los em uma pasta interna do aplicativo para que seja possível excluir automaticamente pelo próprio aplicativo, já tentei como alternativa excluir esses arquivos da pasta DOWNLOADS, mas não consegui...

Segue o código que estou usando para baixar os arquivos, queria adaptar para baixar direto na pasta interna do aplicativo, ou como alternativa caso isso não seja possível, conseguir excluir esses arquivos da pasta DOWNLOADS do Android...

```
    String url = "https://www.site.com/arquivo.pdf"; //Arquivo que vou baixar
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setDescription("Alguma descrição");
    request.setTitle("Algum titulo");

    //A notificação de conslusão só esta disponível a partir da API 11
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    }

    //Salvando o arquivo no diretório de Downloads
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "arquivo.pdf");
   
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Pergunta Editada

Answer (score -1):

Me aconselharam a utilizar o comando "setDestinationInExternalFilesDir" no lugar de "setDestinationInExternalPublicDir", ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY, getFilesDir()+"/MINHA_PASTA/arquivo.pdf");
```

Mas também não funcionou....